# Optimal maximum resolution for cross web/smartphone game development

Tags: android, iphone, unity-game-engine, resolution, desktop

My team is developing a 'game' which will be hosted on a responsive micro site and needs to be accessed from both desktops and smartphones (through a browser, so both android and iphone).

Please don't ask why it is done this way, it has been already been decided by the higher ups and sold to a customer with these specifics.

Question: with the huge variety in android resolutions, dpi and aspect ratios, I need the 'biggest' resolution from which to scale down my art assets for the game. My designer requires to know in what size to create the assets and I am a bit at a loss. Currently my research leads me to believe that either 640x960 or 600 x 1024 would be optimal for phones, but another idea would be to just downscale from 1280x720.

This is important since up-scaling the art assets would be a huge issue.

To clarify, these assets will be created for the game (with unity, which will hopefully help scaling assets and the game), which will run in a frame on the website. This means I am not asking for the size of the webpage (since then I'd just create a responsive webpage), but for the size of the game. I realize that for most phones the game will be down-scaled some.

Thank you for any kind of pointers and help.